Stochastic Geometric Progression
Let $\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_n, \ldots \in \mathbb{R}$, let $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, 
\ldots \in [0, \infty)$ be sequences of numbers.
Let $z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n, \ldots$ be independent random variables such that $\mathbb{E} [z_n] = \mu_n$ and $\mathbb{E} [z_n^2] = \sigma^2_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.
Consider the following iterative progression: $X_0 = x \in \mathbb R$, and $X_{k+1} = (1 - z_k) X_k$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$ (or if you prefer $X_{n+1} = z_n X_n$, please instruct me on the standard notations).
I want to understand what the most general assumptions on $z_n$, $\mu_n$, $\sigma_n$ are such that we have convergence results, with what convergence speed, and for what notions of convergence. For instance, what can we say by only knowing the first two moments? What can we say if the distribution of $z_n$ is discrete? What can we say if they are just uncorrelated but not independent? What can we say about the distance from the solution of the related SDE? What can we say about the distribution of a stopping time?
Thanks a lot in advance,
P

This seems extremely broad. Can you please narrow the question some?

The answer will be "multiple choice''.
It is easier to write $X_{k+1}=z_k X_k$. First, assume that $z_k$ are all positive. Then
$$
\ln(X_{k+1})=\sum_{i=1}^k \xi_i
$$
where $\xi_i=\ln(z_i)$ are independent, so your question boils down to figuring out when the sum of independent random variables converges (and in what sense). These questions have been looked at e.g. here.
Next, if $\mathbb{P}(z_i=0)=0$ for all $i$,  you can study if $\sum_i \ln|z_i|$ converges. If it converges almost surely to value which is not $-\infty$, then $X_k$ converges iff $\sum_i \mathbb{P}(z_i<0)<\infty$, i.e. $X_k$ changes the sign only finitely often (by Borel-Cantelli). On the other hand, if $\sum_i \ln|z_i|=-\infty$ we always would have $X_k\to 0$ a.s.
Finally, if not all $q_i:=\mathbb{P}(z_i=0)$ are equal to zero, then with probability $1-\alpha$ where $\alpha=(1-q_1)(1-q_2)(1-q_3)...$ we have $X_k\to 0$, while with probability $\alpha$ $X_k\to \exp(\sum_{i=1}^\infty \ln(\tilde z_i))$ where $\tilde z_i$ is $z_i$ conditioned on not being zero. (assuming of course that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \ln(\tilde z_i)$ converges).
